# Including more than one formfields in template

Tags: javascript, jquery, django, python-2.7

I am trying to create two different formfields for my django form.

I have written a form which includes both the formfields.

I am using jquery.formset.js But in template, I am calling single function for both the formfields, using `$(formid tbody tr).formset()` , But two add and remove buttons are coming together.

Please, help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a clear explanaition of how to create multiple formsets on one page:

https://code.google.com/p/django-dynamic-formset/wiki/Usage#Using_multiple_Formsets_on_the_same_page